# Specific page look based on user/permissions (SP 2013)

Tags: 2013, permissions, design

I would like to change the look of my sharepoint site based on the user or user permisisons. For example: user1 see white background, user2 see blue background on the same page. Is that possible somehow? Thank you very much for any suggestion!

Answer (score 0):

You can use a DelegateControl.
https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/569897/UsingplusDelegateplusControlplusinplusSharepoint

Inside custom control you can render a style block depending on your logic.